# Without resorting to OData, is there some manual way to locate a specific tag in Taxonomist section?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation

There are close to 7000 Taxonomist badges.

I was curious to see when the [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) tag was created and by whom.

There are currently 116 pages at **Help Center > Badges > Taxonomist**, in no apparent order.

IMHO, it would be useful to see who create a particular tag and when.

Also, at least for me, it would be interesting to see how many tags a given person has created, for example, on page 116, i see that Karl Seguin created the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag.

Perhaps even a view of tags by creator, for example, who created the most tags and what her/his record is.

I'm guessing the above could be done via LINQ to OData queries, however, it would be nice to by able to have some simple canned queries at the Taxonomist page.

Comment: order is by date awarded

Comment: Because I view this as a programming challenge: [based on a user](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/revision/150696/186564/taxonomist-badges-for-a-user), [all tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/revision/150697/186566/all-tag-creators)

Comment: Well what do you know, Jon Skeet made c#.

Comment: This looks like a feature request.